# Build a T flip-flop with enable and reset using only a JK flip-flop (without enable or reset) and some necessary logic gates

Tags: logic-gates, sequential-logic

Can someone help me to check whether my answer is correct or wrong, because I am confused with some of the condition of enable and reset. I am confused if the enable is low and the reset is high, should do flip flop perform reset or not? and also I am confused if both enable and reset are high, should I perform reset or follow the T input?

[image: My answer]

Comment: without checking your truth table in detail, it seems you have the right idea because the RST will always have preference over EN. You want RST to be universally followed in digital logic since it is the only way you can place all elements with memory in a known state

Comment: @DanielV So even if the enable is low and the reset is high, it still performs reset?

Comment: Yes. That would be the preferred behavior. Another question is whether the RST has to assert asynchronously. The way you have it now, the RST will be ignored until the next clock (rising?) edge

Comment: @DanielV Yes, I am trying to build a postive edge triggered T flip flop with enable and reset using JK flip flop. How about if the enable and reset are both high, shoud I follow the reset input or T input (0 = keep, 1 = toggle)?

Comment: even if you are building a clocked FF having asynchronous RST is sometimes preferred. About your second question, yes, RST should trump everything else, EN, input, etc.

Comment: @DanielV ooww okay. lastly, I am wondering as well whether if both my enable and reset are low, should the next state become don't cares or it should keep the current state?

Comment: I think it should keep the current state

Comment: okay thank you very much